# Retrieving file with AWS API gateway that's integrated to S3 with + character in file name

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

We have REST API deployed on AWS API gateway. Some resources are integrated via API GW -> S3 and we are using path override to properly shape request into S3.

We started having some issues with files that contain '+' character in their name. When we checked API GW logs (in test console), we can see that Integration Request rewrites `+` to `%20`, which is completely another character. We even tried to pass `%2B` as part of the file name, but it's still rewritten to `%20`.

This breaks entire integration, because sigv4 request sent to S3 is invalid (because it's signed for different URL). Even if that worked, we would receive another file, because `%2B` was translated to `%20`.

This seems like some bug in AWS API gateway, although I find it weird that there is no article or question about it.

Can anyone tell me what's wrong or how this could be solved?